# Problems with GLEW

Tags: c++, opengl, shared-libraries, glew

I have a problem with GLEW Library, I have a Linux system and I compiled a program with GLFW and GLEW but if I start my program it causes problems.

It outputs this: 
./Test: error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I wrote a bash script with following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/Dokumente/Libraries/glfw-3.2.1-build/src/libglfw.so.3:~/Dokumente/Libraries/glew-2.0.0/lib/libGLEW.so.2.0

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./Test
```

But it doesn't work. It outputs the same error and I am sure the path is right

What can I do?

Comment: ***I am sure the path is right*** It looks wrong to me. I believe you want to put the path of the folder containing the `.so` file not the `.so` file itself.

Comment: I wrote the .so file in this script with its path

Comment: What I mean is ***LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/Dokumente/Libraries/glfw-3.2.1-build/src/libglfw.so.3:~/Dokumente/Libraries/glew-2.0.0/lib/libGLEW.so.2.0*** should be ***LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/Dokumente/Libraries/glfw-3.2.1-build/src:~/Dokumente/Libraries/glew-2.0.0/lib*** I don't think ***~/Dokumente‌​/Libraries/glew-2.0.‌​0/lib/libGLEW.so.2.0*** is a folder containing `libGLEW.so.2.0`

Comment: I don't believe the problem was caused by wrong path. With GLFW it also works with my path but not with GLEW

Answer (score 1):

You can also allow loading of .so's from the same folder the executable is at "Windows Style" by setting the rpath with patchelf:

patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN' your_program_binary

If you want to do this is up to you, of course. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved the problem:

I put all Libraries into /usr/local/lib and change the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to this